# Paper_trail gem stopped working when upgraded ransack to 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ransack, paper-trail-gem

In my rails 7.0.4 app I use:

- activeadmin 3.0.0
- ransack 4.0.0
- paper_trail 15.0.0

I have the page for filtering and sorting history of changes to the data:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register PaperTrail::Version do
  menu label: 'History'
  actions :index

  index title: 'History' do
    id_column
    column :item
    column :event
    column 'Author' do |version|
      User.where(id: version.whodunnit.to_i).first
    end
    column 'Changes', :object_changes
    column :created_at
  end

  filter :item_type
  filter :item_id, as: :numeric
  filter :created_at, input_html: {autocomplete: :off}
  filter :whodunnit, label: 'Author', as: :numeric
  filter :object_changes
end
```

Before I upgraded to activeadmin 3.0.0 and ransack 4.0.0, everything worked fine.
After upgrade, I am getting this error on every page:
"Ransack needs ... attributes explicitly allowlisted as ...".
This was easily fixed for all pages except the history page, where the error states:

> Ransack needs PaperTrail::Version attributes explicitly allowlisted as
> searchable. Define a `ransackable_attributes` class method in your `PaperTrail::Version`
> model, watching out for items you DON'T want searchable (for
> example, `encrypted_password`, `password_reset_token`, `owner` or
> other sensitive information). You can use the following as a base:

```rb
class PaperTrail::Version < ApplicationRecord

  # ...

  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    ["created_at", "event", "id", "item_id", "item_type", "object", "object_changes", "whodunnit"]
  end

  # ...

end
```

My `config/initializers/paper_trail.rb` is not much different and I think I added the `ransackable_attributes` method correctly:

```rb
module PaperTrail
  class Version < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
      %w[created_at event id item_id item_type object object_changes whodunnit]
    end

    def user
      User.where(id: self.whodunnit.to_i).first
    end
  end
end

PaperTrail::Model::ClassMethods.module_eval do
  alias_method :old_has_paper_trail, :has_paper_trail
  def has_paper_trail(options = {})
    options[:ignore] ||= []
    options[:ignore] += [:created_at, :updated_at, :current_sign_in_at, :last_sign_in_at, :current_sign_in_ip, :last_sign_in_ip, :sign_in_count]
    old_has_paper_trail(options)
  end
end
```

But the error stays the same. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A littly bit silly, but restarting the server solved the issue.

Since I had `PaperTrail::Version` as an initializer, the change didn't take effect without server restart. Changes to other models took effect even without restart.